# htaccess remove .php file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am Using htaccess, i am trying to stop .php displaying on files in the address bar. i currently have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pagename=$1.php
```

and index.php has

```
include $_GET["pagename"];
```

if the url is `domain.com/customer/tickets/openticket`

it should rewrite to `domain.com/customer/tickets/openticket.php`

how can i make this apply only to

domain.com/customer and my.domain.com ?

Answer (score 0):

First, check PHP extension URL_rewrite
When below code find a openticket on your URL, rewrite it to openticket.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule     ^openticket/?$      openticket.php          [L,NC]


RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /             [L,R=301]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: its not just the openticket.php file, its all the files in the customer/ directory

Answer (score 0):

The url rewrite rules are not magic. You can not just write a system with a thousand pages and then use the rule to do what you want. You need to write the system already thinking about the rules. 
What can you do in this case is to rewrite all the rules saying that when you find certain name in the url, will draw particular file. I do not particularly know magic to it. 
It would be something like:

```
 RewriteRule      ^page1/?$     page1.php     [L,NC]
 RewriteRule      ^page2/?$     page2.php     [L,NC]
 RewriteRule      ^page3/?$     page3.php     [L,NC]
 RewriteRule      ^page4/?$     page4.php     [L,NC]
```

And etc..
If any other user to know a magic to it, please let me know.

Update:

Maybe you can try some like as this (it is just a idea/magic):

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)?$ /$1.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pagename=$1.php [L]
```

That will only try to add the php extension when it's inside the "customer" folder or if the host is "my.domain.com". You can bypass the `index.php` file entirely by simply replacing the last line with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

In order to *remove* the php extension when someone puts something like `http://domain.com/customer/tickets/openticket.php` in their browser's address bar, you'll need this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/customer/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pagename=$1.php
```

Comment: when i go to domain.com/customer/tickets/openticket it shows page not found